# how to load an ELF file all at once in linux?

Tags: c, linux

I'm using a NFS file system to load ELF file from a remote NFS server, the file system is mounted as read-only, once the ELF file is loaded and run, it supposed to have no read interaction with NFS server.
But as we know, the ELF loader may not load all segment into process virtual space at first, when it encounters page fault, it will continue to load the missing segment, which may lead to read interaction with NFS server.
my question is how to let the kernel to loader all the ELF segment before it start to run, which can ensure that there is no read interaction with NFS server at runtime.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: copy to local storage, then run

Comment: i forgot to mention that it has no local storage except ramfs, which is also very limited.

Comment: If your storage is limited then you're out of luck. The reason for lazy loading is that your code may use one small routine in a shared library but your method will require loading the whole thing.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to optimise here? Because preloading causes both higher network usage and memory consumption.

Comment: the processes are all about real-time alghothrim, and they are a little big, but not that big. if i copy them to local, at least i need to prepare one storage memory and one runtime memory for them. but if i preload them, i only need to prepare one runtime memory for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your program call [`mlockall()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mlockall) when it starts:

> `mlockall()` locks all pages mapped into the address space of the calling process. This includes the pages of the code, data and stack segment, as well as shared libraries, user space kernel data, shared memory, and memory-mapped files. All mapped pages are guaranteed to be resident in RAM when the call returns successfully; the pages are guaranteed to stay in RAM until later unlocked.

Note that you have to be root for this, or have the `CAP_IPC_LOCK` capability, since ordinary user processes aren't allowed to forcibly hog physical memory this way.

Comment: it seems helpful to me, i'll give it a try, thank you very much.